# C# Client2Client

Tags: c#, networking, httplistener

I'm trying to create a simple Client2Client console chat, for learning purposes, using C# and, blame my lack of experience in networking, I'm stuck.

From what I've been able to deduce, and correct me if I'm wrong, I should create a Server .exe and a Client .exe.
The thing is, I know how to use HttpListener to get requests from a client and then send a response to him, but I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to get data from a client and then send it to another client.

I tried Google but my doubts are as strong as before. Any suggestion would be extremely helpful :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should add a minimal code example to your question. Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Thank you Jeroen :)
Thing is, I'm asking this question because I don't know what code to write, If my question brings to any helpful answer, and I encounter other problems during realization, I'll be sure to do as you said. ;)

Comment: You will want to describe what you want better. And, though Stackoverflow excels as a programming Q&A site, it's not very good at "how do I start" questions.  Do you want to create a "peer-to-peer" chat application (by the way, that's the usual name) that works between two computers separated by the internet?  If so, because of security, that's very hard to do (and extremely hard to do in a secure fashion).  If you just want to have two apps on your desktop (or on two computers (on the same subnet) in your house), then that's a do-able thing.  Look for Peer to peer (P2P) samples

Comment: Hi Flydog. :)
My Idea is to simply have 2 console applications that send to each other strings over the internet. It is very hard for me because I'm ignorant on the matter, although I already know how to code at a pretty decent level.
Not something for business or serious use, of course, since it's just for learning. I just need to build something that works so to learn how to do it!

Thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: Oh and I've already built a working app to make two processes on the same pc communicate. You are right in saying it's infinitely easier!